# Why does AliceBundle Fixture DateTime give me an unexpected value?

Tags: symfony, datetime, alice-fixtures

I'm currently working on a project in which I create fixtures with Alice-bundle to run tests to make sure my API-endpoints work properly. Everything works fine, except for the DateTime properties.

No matter what string I pass it, eg: `<dateTime('2019-09-23 14:00:00')>`, it always gives me the wrong date and time, usually something like: `1998-10-25T14:29:45+01:00`.

Even using `<dateTime('now')>` does not work -- it gives me some pre-2000s date & time as well, while that's exactly what some examples I'd found do use.

A fixture could look something like this:

`Path\To\Task\Entity:
  my_task:
    title: 'My tasks'
    description: 'These are all the tasks just for me!!!'
    startsAt: <dateTime('now')>
    endsAt: <dateTime('now')>
    createdBy: '@some_higher_user'`

Ideally I just want to pass it a string so I can define both a Date and Time and make sure it works properly, in the right format.

And help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking here https://github.com/nelmio/alice/blob/master/doc/advanced-guide.md#functions we read:

> function can be a Faker or a PHP native (or registered in the global scope) function.

So I would recommend trying a PHP native function that creates a `\DateTime` object

```
<date_create_from_format ( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' , '2019-09-23 14:00:00')>
// or
<date_create('now')>
```

Comment: This works nicely and seems a neater solution than passing the two exact same DateTime strings to `dateTimeBetween()`. Thank you!

Comment: Nice. You should mark this as correct answer instead of mine, @TienusMcVinger

Answer (score 1):

That's how it works. The `<dateTime()>` function takes an argument called `$max`. So what it does is create a date between a starting date (not sure which one, probably something in the 1900 range or so) and that `$max` argument.

I guess you will want to use `<dateTimeBetween()>` which takes a startDate and an endDate to create a fake date between them. So I suppose if startDate = endDate, then you'll get the desired fixed date.

Take a look at [fzaninotto/Faker](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker#fakerproviderdatetime) library documentation. It's the library used by AliceBundle to actually fake data. There you can see what DateTime related functions you can use.